# Change the offset alone in a JodaDate without changing the date and time information

Tags: java, datetime, date, jodatime, datetimeoffset

I get a String like this "2012-07-01T06:00 +02:00" as input. It is in CET.
But this String should have been "2012-07-01T06:00 +01:00".

We can't change anything on the original source.

Now I want to get that Date as "2012-07-01T06:00 +01:00" expected by my system.

I am using Joda Library.
I read the date specifying DateTimeZone as Germany.

On this date, once I specify Europe/London as DateTimeZone, the date becomes 
"2012-07-01T05:00 +01:00" (which is not expected value by my system, See the change in Hour).

Is there a way to do without using String manipulation ?

Comment: Where does the string come from - from your 2 examples - could the server have the wrong time

Comment: The source of the String is also doing String manipulation and they are setting it wrong. Unfortunately, that can't be fixed immediately, as there has to be a study on Side Effects before touching it. Its a common module.

Comment: This is doing exactly what it should do, cet is +1 compared to gmt. Why bother getting the time from your source if you are not trusting it ?

Comment: Joda is working as expected. I got no doubts on that. I just wanted to check atleast whether I can do it on the right way in my application (instead of adding one more layer of ugly string manipulation)

Comment: "whether I can do it on the right way" what exactly do you want to do... change the time and date of a DateTime to something else ?

Comment: `2012-07-01T06:00 +02:00` = `2012-07-01T05:00 +01:00` = `2012-07-01T04:00 +00:00`. Why do you want to change the right thing into something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have damaged input, the only way to parse it is to fix it using string manipulation functions and then use date parser with specified time offset.

If you know that the string contains time in +01:00 offset, you should remove the offset from the string using `substring()` and use DateTimeFormat with explicitly specified `withZone(DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(1))` completely ignoring input's offset.

But it is only if you 100% sure that the problem is in the input string.